# unnest_tokens and ERROR in UseMethod("pull")

Tags: r, tidytext

I'm having problems using unnest_tokens on a particular dataset.

I've tried using non-standard evaluation, i.e. unnest_tokens_, to pull the column from the dataframe. However this feature is now deprecated.

I've subset the singular column I want to work with, transformed to a tibble and have added a column name.

```
unnestedSymptoms <- TidySymptoms %>% 
unnest_tokens(word, Text)
```

However this is throwing the following error:

> Error in UseMethod("pull") :
> no applicable method for 'pull' applied to an object of class "character">

As I'm not directly calling pull() I don't know where to go from here. Any help appreciated

Output from Subset Dataframe, one column:

> structure(c("Slight fever the day of the injections. The next night he
> Stopped breathing in the middle of the night twice. Temperature was 96
> degrees Fahrenheit when arriving at the emergency room.",  "Slight
> fever the day of the injections. The next night he Stopped breathing
> in the middle of the night twice. Temperature was 96 degrees
> Fahrenheit when arriving at the emergency room.",  "Slight fever the
> day of the injections. The next night he Stopped breathing in the
> middle of the night twice. Temperature was 96 degrees Fahrenheit when
> arriving at the emergency room.",  "Slight fever the day of the
> injections. The next night he Stopped breathing in the middle of the
> night twice. Temperature was 96 degrees Fahrenheit when arriving at
> the emergency room.",  "Slight fever the day of the injections. The
> next night he Stopped breathing in the middle of the night twice.
> Temperature was 96 degrees Fahrenheit when arriving at the emergency
> room.",  "Slight fever the day of the injections. The next night he
> Stopped breathing in the middle of the night twice. Temperature was 96
> degrees Fahrenheit when arriving at the emergency room.",  "Slight
> fever the day of the injections. The next night he Stopped breathing
> in the middle of the night twice. Temperature was 96 degrees
> Fahrenheit when arriving at the emergency room.",  "Slight fever the
> day of the injections. The next night he Stopped breathing in the
> middle of the night twice. Temperature was 96 degrees Fahrenheit when
> arriving at the emergency room.",  "Abnormal eye movements (multiple
> an hour) the following day (12/19). He was taken to local emergency
> room and admitted to neurology for continuous video EEG, sedated for
> brain MRI, ophthalmology exam. All tests were normal, but movements
> have continued. He saw ophthalmology for a dilated exam today,
> 1/6/2020, and they referred us to neuro ophthalmology.",  "Pt showed
> at the ER on 12/25/2020 after falling mid walk.  Pt left hand was
> rhythmically opening and closing.  Head was twitching and left arm and
> left leg twitching-sx lasted 10min.  Fever of 103 documented by EMS,
> vaccines 1 wk prior to the ER visit.  Sx resolved 2 hrs after seizure.
> Diagnosed with ? atypical febrile seizure.  Patient then sent to
> Center where he had an EEG and neurology consult.  Dx with complex
> febrile seizure- had felt possible febrile seizure vs epilepsy vs
> genetic predisposition secondary to TMPRSS3 genetic mutation.",  "Pt
> showed at the ER on 12/25/2020 after falling mid walk.  Pt left hand
> was rhythmically opening and closing.  Head was twitching and left arm
> and left leg twitching-sx lasted 10min.  Fever of 103 documented by
> EMS, vaccines 1 wk prior to the ER visit.  Sx resolved 2 hrs after
> seizure. Diagnosed with ? atypical febrile seizure.  Patient then sent
> to Center where he had an EEG and neurology consult.  Dx with complex
> febrile seizure- had felt possible febrile seizure vs epilepsy vs
> genetic predisposition secondary to TMPRSS3 genetic mutation.",  "Pt
> showed at the ER on 12/25/2020 after falling mid walk.  Pt left hand
> was rhythmically opening and closing.  Head was twitching and left arm
> and left leg twitching-sx lasted 10min.  Fever of 103 documented by
> EMS, vaccines 1 wk prior to the ER visit.  Sx resolved 2 hrs after
> seizure. Diagnosed with ? atypical febrile seizure.  Patient then sent
> to Center where he had an EEG and neurology consult.  Dx with complex
> febrile seizure- had felt possible febrile seizure vs epilepsy vs
> genetic predisposition secondary to TMPRSS3 genetic mutation.",  "Pt
> showed at the ER on 12/25/2020 after falling mid walk.  Pt left hand
> was rhythmically opening and closing.  Head was twitching and left arm
> and left leg twitching-sx lasted 10min.  Fever of 103 documented by
> EMS, vaccines 1 wk prior to the ER visit.  Sx resolved 2 hrs after
> seizure. Diagnosed with ? atypical febrile seizure.  Patient then sent
> to Center where he had an EEG and neurology consult.  Dx with complex
> febrile seizure- had felt possible febrile seizure vs epilepsy vs
> genetic predisposition secondary to TMPRSS3 genetic mutation.",  "Pt
> showed at the ER on 12/25/2020 after falling mid walk.  Pt left hand
> was rhythmically opening and closing.  Head was twitching and left arm
> and left leg twitching-sx lasted 10min.  Fever of 103 documented by
> EMS, vaccines 1 wk prior to the ER visit.  Sx resolved 2 hrs after
> seizure. Diagnosed with ? atypical febrile seizure.  Patient then sent
> to Center where he had an EEG and neurology consult.  Dx with complex
> febrile seizure- had felt possible febrile seizure vs epilepsy vs
> genetic predisposition secondary to TMPRSS3 genetic mutation.",  "Pt
> showed at the ER on 12/25/2020 after falling mid walk.  Pt left hand
> was rhythmically opening and closing.  Head was twitching and left arm
> and left leg twitching-sx lasted 10min.  Fever of 103 documented by
> EMS, vaccines 1 wk prior to the ER visit.  Sx resolved 2 hrs after
> seizure. Diagnosed with ? atypical febrile seizure.  Patient then sent
> to Center where he had an EEG and neurology consult.  Dx with complex
> febrile seizure- had felt possible febrile seizure vs epilepsy vs
> genetic predisposition secondary to TMPRSS3 genetic mutation.",  "Pt
> showed at the ER on 12/25/2020 after falling mid walk.  Pt left hand
> was rhythmically opening and closing.  Head was twitching and left arm
> and left leg twitching-sx lasted 10min.  Fever of 103 documented by
> EMS, vaccines 1 wk prior to the ER visit.  Sx resolved 2 hrs after
> seizure. Diagnosed with ? atypical febrile seizure.  Patient then sent
> to Center where he had an EEG and neurology consult.  Dx with complex
> febrile seizure- had felt possible febrile seizure vs epilepsy vs
> genetic predisposition secondary to TMPRSS3 genetic mutation.",  "Pt
> showed at the ER on 12/25/2020 after falling mid walk.  Pt left hand
> was rhythmically opening and closing.  Head was twitching and left arm
> and left leg twitching-sx lasted 10min.  Fever of 103 documented by
> EMS, vaccines 1 wk prior to the ER visit.  Sx resolved 2 hrs after
> seizure. Diagnosed with ? atypical febrile seizure.  Patient then sent
> to Center where he had an EEG and neurology consult.  Dx with complex
> febrile seizure- had felt possible febrile seizure vs epilepsy vs
> genetic predisposition secondary to TMPRSS3 genetic mutation.",
> "Throat closing, palpitation, lightheadedness, cough with
> bronchospasm" ), .Names = c("Text", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA,  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
>
> > 

```
# Remove NA
AllData21NAGONE <- na.omit(AllData21)
AllData21NAGONE_tbl <- AllData21NAGONE %>% as_tibble(AllData21NAGONE)

# Subset Col to work with
TidySymptoms <- AllData21NAGONE_tbl$SYMPTOM_TEXT 
# Add column names
names(TidySymptoms) <- c("Text")
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data with dput() ?

Comment: I've added sample with dput(), can see colnames at bottom have only appended to first row??

Comment: PLease don't share this as screenshot, but paste the content from dput... to your question.

Comment: Without all of the information, I'm pretty sure it's because you have a vector - I know it says it works with a vector - that being said, try a one-column data frame... I was able to duplicate your error when I used a vector.

Comment: Converted to dataframe and it worked!! Thank you, I thought it had to be a tibble for unnest_tokens. Super